# api platform.com - Unsuported Media Type

Tags: api-platform.com

I just added API platform to existing Symfony 4.4 project

> $ composer require api

but can't get any response in Supported Media Type from it. Documentation says it should work out of the box but I'm out of luck. Probably something is missing in my setup although it looks just like in examples:

config/packages/api_platform.yaml

```
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
    patch_formats:
        json: ['application/merge-patch+json']
    swagger:
        versions: [3]
```

Entity/Main/ContentProviders.php

```
/**
 * ContentProviders
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="content_providers", indexes={
 *     @ORM\Index(name="title", columns={"title"}),
 * })
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"post"},
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "get"={},
 *          "put"
 *     },
 *     shortName="content_providers",
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"content_providers:read"}, "swagger_definition_name"="Read"},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"content_providers:write"}, "swagger_definition_name"="Write"}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
...
```

And if I call

> curl -X GET "https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/content_providers/1" -H
> "accept: application/ld+json"

It says

```
{"@context":"\/api\/contexts\/Error","@type":"hydra:Error","hydra:title":"An error occurred","hydra:description":"Format \u0027jsonld\u0027 not supported, handler must be implemented"
```

By default, JSON-LD format should be enabled https://api-platform.com/docs/core/content-negotiation/ but I also tried to add formats lines to

config/packages/api_platform.yaml

```
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
    formats:
        jsonld:   ['application/ld+json']
        jsonhal:  ['application/hal+json']
        jsonapi:  ['application/vnd.api+json']
        json:     ['application/json']
        xml:      ['application/xml', 'text/xml']
        yaml:     ['application/x-yaml']
        csv:      ['text/csv']
        html:     ['text/html']
    patch_formats:
        json: ['application/merge-patch+json']
    swagger:
        versions: [3]
```

however this not helped.

Comment: Hey @dMedia! From what I can see, the error is coming from FOSRestBundle, not from API Platform. You may still have some misconfiguration in API Platform, but it's hard to know because FOSRestBundle is throwing the error. You could try uninstalling or disabling the view part of FOSRestBundle and seeing if that makes things work or at least shows a different error. Cheers!

Comment: Correct answer, thank you. After FOSRestBundle removal everything started to work as expected.